# Is 't Hooft cellular automaton compatible with Floridi's Informational (Structural) Realism?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, quantum-physics, computation, realism, structuralism

Informational (Structural) Realism (by Luciano Floridi) relates to digital physics ideas (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_physics)

As Floridi himself says in one of his articles (http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/4076/):

"On the other hand, pancomputationalists like Lloyd, who describes the universe not as a Turing Machine but as a quantum computer, can still hold an analogue or hybrid ontology"

This means that those models from theoretical scientists that describe the universe as being a quantum computer, and not as a classical Turing machine, are compatible with Informational (Structural) Realism. Am I wrong?

But what about models describing the universe as a cellular automata (like nobel laureate 't Hooft's models (one example: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9903084)? Since they describe quantum mechanics, does that mean that his models are like quantum computers? Then, if they are, does it mean that his models are compatible or are a scientific approach/descrtiption for informational (Structural) Realism?